# Why use init-method property if the same thing could be done in the constructor?

Tags: java, spring

I am bit confused about usability of the `init-method` property. Can anybody provide me with a use case where doing something in the constructor will not make sense and `init-method` property would be good fit?

As per my understanding one would be using `init-method` property while defining bean if on bean creation some task needs to be performed but this can be done in bean's constructor as well.

Answer (score 2):

There are several use-cases for `init-method`. The most important is when the class initialization logic requires several properties to be set, but they cannot be set via the constructor. In this case, the flow would be:

1. Construct the bean (default constructor)
2. Inject the properties via setter methods
3. Run the init method

Another useful case for `init-method` is when modernizing legacy code. Some classes in old code bases simply have these methods, for whatever good or bad reason. Instead of forcing you to rewrite the code, Spring offers you an easy way to consume it.

Comment: that was my point too. As you are also suggesting that constructor gets called first so why not do something in constructor itself. Can you elaborate use case more? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess all injections made via properties are in place when init is called.